# Creating a drop-down list in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When I click the button with an arrow symbol, the list of items available should be displayed as a list. Could anyone help me with the code for developing this for an iPhone application?

Comment: See this answer: It will help you in creating your dropdown:http://stackoverflow.com/a/12066726/846372

Comment: you can use 
https://github.com/satishazad/SAMenuDropDown

Answer (score 13):

UIPickerView is the correct control, the one that iOS users expect, and the control specified by the Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

Even on a web page in Safari, wherever there would normally be a drop down a picker is displayed instead. Go with the picker if you at all can.

Comment: To add to this, Microsoft doesn't provide or recommend drop down lists on Windows Phone 7 either. Some PC metaphors just don't work well at all on small screens. I agree that UIPickerView is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone does not have a built-in dropdown / selection list. You need to implement this yourself. [This link](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/generic-selection-list-controller.html) contains a similar implementation using table view.

EDIT: UIPickerView is another option as pointed in other answers. You should also consider this.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a drop down list?  The standard here is to use a `UIPickerView` (especially on the iPhone) like Safari does whenever you have a drop down list.  Not only is it standard, but it's way simpler than what I'm about to propose.

Well, if your answer is 'yes, it has to be a drop down list on the same screen', you're stuck implementing it yourself.  This could be rather painful, but off the top of my head, your best bet would be to to create a `UITableView` (which will act as your PickerView) and create a custom `UITableViewCell` that only has a label (or maybe label + icon, or however you wish).  Whenever the user presses your arrow (sic)sumbol, you display the view by either animating it in underneath the arrow or by just making it appear.  Remember, you will have to have some controller acting as the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

If your answer is 'no, that sounds complicated' go with the picker.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the actual question though, there is a discussion here:

[How to create a dropdown tableview like Vine App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690105/how-to-create-a-dropdown-tableview-like-vine-app)